# How to update the navigation on an ajax page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, pjax

So I have a rails application that has two different navigation headers. One that is used for the majority of pages and another navigation header that is used for only a few pages. Additionally since the navigation is loaded in the application.html.erb page (shared between all the pages of the application) the navigation html is never refreshed from the server unless the user refreshes the page. And since each page is loaded through ajax (using pjax) it means that when I move between two pages that need different navigation headers the navigation header is not updated.

I have a few solutions that are possible but I don't like them since I don't want to have to add code to every view that I have. The main solution being move the navigation header into the views (instead of the global application.html.erb), or add javascript to every page that checks that the navigation is the correct one and if not replace it. But for replacing it I'm not sure how to load the html which is a partial and contains data from the models.

Note: directly visiting each url works fine.

I feel like I'm missing some easy approach since this feels like it should be a fairly common problem but I am unable to find anything while searching.

Edit: and I am using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only two navs, generate them both in your layout and hide them.

```
<div id="nav">
  <div id="nav1" class="nav" style="display: none"><a href="#">Nav1</a></div>
  <div id="nav2" class="nav" style="display: none"><a href="#">Nav2</a></div>
</div>
```

In your page's JS, create a function that will show the one you want. When you update the page via pjax, you'll want to pass in some JS to execute, calling chooseNav with the one you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function chooseNav(sel) {
    $('#nav .nav').hide();
    $('#nav' + sel).show();
  }

  $(function() {
    chooseNav(1);  // Default nav to load when page loads
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, this is a really nice and simple solution. I had already started developing a solution with an extra controller and server-generated javascript that would execute every time a navigation change was needed. Will try this now.

Comment: After some quick prototyping this is working nicely, although I need to do something to get the javascript to run when the back button is pressed, probably need to listen to the pjax events. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Jason,
I am assuming that you are looking for a way to change the color of the tab that's active.

If the ajax page being rendered is a show view add the following to the show.js.erb:

Since, you have not included the code, I am making two assumptions.

**Assumption 1:** I am assuming it looks something like this if the second page is active:

```
<div class="top_menu_bar">
<a class="menu_link controller_1" href="/controller_1">The First Controller</a>
<a class="menu_link controller_2 highlighted" href="/controller_2">The Second Controller</a>
<a class="menu_link controller_3" href="/controller_3">The Third Controller</a>
</div>
```

Please note that if you do not have the controller names in the class for your anchor tags, you can easily add those.  It will simplify your JQuery.  But, the key part to the solution is following the two steps I outline shortly.  You can always modify the JQuery selectors according to your code.

**Assumption 2:** I am assuming you have a css rule for a.highlighted that will make any anchor with highlighted class stand out from the rest.

Now, with those assumption in place let's talk about the two-step solution to change the navigation, when you click a link or button on the page that uses the Ajax request to load say the :show view associated with the tab controller_3.

You need to do the following two things:

```
Step 1: Remove the "highlighted" class from the anchor of
      controller_2
Step 2: Add the "highlighted" class to the anchor of controller 3.
```

You can do this by adding the following in your show.js.erb file:

```
$('.highlighted').removeClass("highlighted");
$('.<%= controller_name %>').addClass("highlighted);
```

As you can see we are inserting the controller_name dynamically when show.js.erb gets served.  Please note that you will still need the period prefix.

I believe that should do the trick.  There might be syntax errors in the above code, so please take the overall concept and apply it to your situation.  For your convenience I have put together a small sample on jsfiddle to demonstrate the javascript portion of the code.  Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/593ce/4/.

I hope this works out for you and you find this answer acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go ahead with replacing the navigation with the appropriate partial, you can place the following in your AJAX response (assuming you are using jquery):

```
$('#navigation').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'partial') %>');
```

Comment: Hmmm, that looks promising, I'll try it out